# How to properly use the setTempo method in midi.js

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm using [midi.js](https://github.com/sergi/jsmidi/blob/master/midi.js) for a small [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-piano/dfgofljdjaikmlbofdkohdglmpoonfkd/reviews) that I'm making, and while I'm able to export note events, I cannot figure how to change the MIDI tempo using the setTempo method.

I'm able to run the method using:

```
 var tempo = {type:META_TEMPO,data:[0x0F,0x42,0x40]};
 events.push(new MetaEvent(tempo));
```

I'm pushing this event to the beginning of the events array, before any note event.

I later checked the values of that events array before exporting to MIDI and the  setTempo meta event's values are 255,81 following by the data property's values.

I've tried using 0x0F,0x42,0x40 which should produce a bpm of 60 but it doesn't work.

Had anyone figured how to work with that method?

Thanks for reading!